# Simple css hover issue

Tags: html, css, hover, webkit

I have this simple HTML:

```
<div class="candy">
  <p style="position: absolute">COLLECTIONS</p>
  <div>
    <img class="candy" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="http://www.backlabel.com/eshop/img/cms/collections/collections.jpg" width="467" height="702" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this simple CSS:

```
.candy {
  -webkit-transition: all 0,3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0,3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0,3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0,3s ease;
  transition: all 0,3s ease;
}

.candy:hover {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(0.3);
}
```

When hovering the image the opacity filter is not applied.

I'm using Prestashop, if it can be helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Replace `0,3` with `0.3`. Works for me: **http://output.jsbin.com/kakelogujo**

Comment: are you trying to hover on the div and effect the img, or hover on the img and change the img's opacity?

Comment: Yes i have tried to switch them, and i have correct the '0,3' with '0.3'. NOW WORK BUT, only on the first line of the image (if you hover between the background and the top of image it work, but if you hover on the middle of the image it doesnt' work).

Comment: you can view in live from www.backlabel.com/eshop

Comment: Yes of course! 

When i hover on the red box works, but on the blue one not.

![over issue] (http://www.backlabel.com/hover.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
        <h3><a href="#">COLLECTION</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="image-block">
        <img src="dreamy_1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;

        }
        .image-block{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
            -ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
            transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
        }
        .image-block img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .content-block{
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        .content-block h3{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .content-block a{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .transparent{
            -webkit-filter: opacity(0.3);

        }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content-block a').hover (function(){
            $('.image-block').toggleClass('transparent');
        })
    })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have correct the '0,3' with '0.3'. NOW WORK BUT, only on the first line of the image (if you hover between the background and the top of image it work, but if you hover on the middle of the image it doesnt' work).

Comment: you can view in live from www.backlabel.com/eshop

Comment: I think you may describe it in more details or can you give some visual mock-up?

Comment: Yes of course! 

When i hover on the red box works, but on the blue one not.

! [over issue] (http://www.backlabel.com/hover.jpg) .

Comment: I think you had a mistake, it's the other image with different hover.. the "collection" banner.

Comment: You can use any image with any dimensions.

Comment: I have found why it's doesn't work:

The others threes banners (with jQuery) make issues with the other images.. i don't know the specific, but when i have deleted these elements, everything comes to works great!

Comment: Glad you found it yourself. You question doesn't indicated any jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
img.candy:hover {
 opacity: 0.3;
}
```